# Old sci-fi book about a tribe of miniature people who discover that they live on a spaceship circling the Earth

Tags: story-identification, novel

Sometime in the '80s, I read a story about a tribe living in a community where they encounter 'giants.' Later, it turns out that the tribe members are actually mutated and the giants are normal humans. Also, they discover that they live on a spaceship circling the Earth, and that they are the result of some failed experiment.

The book was published as part of a series with blue backs. Can't remember the title or publisher.

Comment: Note: accepted by comment on answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is ***[Non-Stop](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/384579.Non_Stop)*** (1958) by Brian W. Aldiss.

> Curiosity was discouraged in the Greene tribe. Its members lived out their lives in cramped Quarters, hacking away at the encroaching ponics. As to where they were - that was forgotten.
> Roy Complain decides to find out. With the renegade priest Marapper, he moves into unmapped territory, where they make a series of discoveries which turn their universe upside-down...

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Stop_(novel)):

> **The novel's protagonist, Roy Complain, lives in a culturally-primitive tribe on a massive generation ship which has descended into a uncivilized state.** The ship is overgrown by vegetation and the inhabitants have clustered into warring tribes. In Roy's tribe, curiosity is discouraged, and life is solitary, poor, and short. With a small group, he leaves his home and ventures into uncharted territory in the ship. The consequent discoveries will change his perception of the entire universe.
>
> [...]
>
> On their journey, the group encounters other tribes of varying levels of sophistication. **Complain is also briefly captured by humanoid 'Giants' of legend, who release him with no explanation.** Complain's party eventually join the more sophisticated society of the 'Forwards'. Here, **they learn that the space-craft is a multi-generational starship returning from a newly colonised planet in the Procyon star system. In a previous generation, the ship's inhabitants had suffered from a pandemic because of an alien amino acid found in the waters of the Procyon planet. Law and order began to collapse, and knowledge of the ship and its purpose was eventually almost entirely lost throughout the vessel.** Since the 'Catastrophe', 23 generations have passed so far.
>
> [...]
>
> **It is then revealed that the ship has been moored outside Earth's atmosphere for a number of years. The 'Giants' are merely normal-sized Earth-humans who have been attempting to improve the conditions of the ship's inhabitants by slowly repairing the vessel.**
>
> [...]
>
> **The rulers of Earth have been reluctant to integrate the ship-dwellers into Earth's civilization because the epidemic survivors have mutated to live four times faster than Earth's population.**

Comment: Interestingly, the original US title was *Starship*, which sort of gave the game away...

Comment: Wow, yes, that's the book! I went to check on Amazon and immediately ordered a copy. Thanks a lot!